# Python iterating through a ui enum

Tags: python, color-management

I am trying to print all of the looks that are installed inside of the colormanagement look enum. Currently I have:

```
for look in bpy.context.scene.view_settings.bl_rna.properties['look'].enum_items:
    print(look.name)
    print(look.description)
    print(look.value)
```

but what this gives me is

```
None
Do not modify image in an artistic manner
0
```

and nothing else.

It does not change from `None` when you select a different look. How can I make this print each possible value?

Comment: Added color management and removed my answer.  Generally you can list the enum property members by looking at `bl_rna.properties["the_enum_prop"].enum_items` this doesn't appear to be the case for color management enums.  btw in your question you are pretty much saying for character in string.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You can get the looks from the `version/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio`  data file.  Could use http://opencolorio.org/developers/bindings/PythonAPI.html or parse the file for `- !<Look>' and the details there.  The items list of the enum is prob populated  in source code based on this file.

Comment: ok, I will take a look into it.